# Video resolution during playback when using the multimedia package

Tags: beamer, graphics, multimedia

I am using beamer for a presentation. In a slide a have a video ( I am using multimedia package):

```
\begin{frame}
    \centering{
 \movie[showcontrols]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.8\textheight]{figures/logoPlay}}{figures/Untitled3.avi}
}
\end{frame}
```

I use Debut (Video capture software). The output resolution of the video is ok, but when i import it in latex and after opening adobe reader the resolution is not the same (Part of the captures follows):
[image]

Its not tottaly clear in the picture but there are differences which i am afraid that in a projector will make the video not clear at all. 
Is there an option to `\movie` that i can increase the resolution? I could not find the documantation of the multimedia package in net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if a video is played in an embedded player, it is re-sampled to the actual number of pixels the video area covers on the screen. This may lead to details getting lost and other undesirable artifacts. The size of the video area depends on its relative size w.r.t. the PDF page size, the zoom-state of the PDF page within the PDF viewer and the window size of the PDF viewer.

The only way to play a video at its original resolution, that is, pixel-true without interpolation, is to play it in a detached (floating) window.

You can do this using the `media9` package and its `windowed=<width>x<height>` option. You need to know the original video dimensions `<width>` and `<height>`, both measured in pixels, beforehand.

Example using the video file `cube.mp4` and `cubeposter.png` from the `media9` package. The original video size is 192x176 pixels^2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Video}
  \includemedia[
    addresource=cube.mp4,
    windowed=192x176,
    flashvars={
      source=cube.mp4     % same path as in addresource!
     &loop=true           % loop video
    }
  ]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try it with the original video dimensions (1920x1080) the same as the screen, it is offset a little to the right, with the left edge of the beamer slide visible, and the right side of the video cut off.

Comment: @Liam Did you try the windowed option as `windowed=1920x1080@tl` to position it at the top left screen corner? And put Acroread in full-screen mode. That's all we can do.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet, but I will. (Acroread was in full screen mode.)